# How to loop cell values from excel into a websites text box with VBA?

Tags: excel, list, loops, vba

I have a list in excel that has roughly 1800 values in it (numbers, letters, etc.) I have to enter each one individually into a website with vba. Is there a way to loop these values starting with cell **A1**, then **A2**...**A1800** into the website one at a time?

```
Set svalue1 = ie.document.getElementById("Txt Box ID")
 svalue1.Value = "9B"

ie.document.getElementsByName("Button Name").Item.Click
```

Above is how I enter one value into that text box then click submit to get the data I need. I then have to return to the homepage after the data is scraped for value **A1**, copy **cell** **A2** and overwrite the textbox to input **A2** then scrape the data for that value too. That process needs to be repeated 1800 times All help is appreciated!

Comment: you would want to write a standard for each or for loop to iterate through your cells (for i = 1 to lastrow) and ensure that there is a *wait* between steps, as the ie pages need time to load.  use your input code, wait, followed by your scrape code (not present in post, but assuming you have some), wait, then iterate through loop,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like below, this will open up your URL in internet explorer, then loop from A2 to your last cell on Column A with data and enter that value into the "Txt Box ID", it will then click on the button, then you can get the values you require before going back to the initial URL to repeat the process until the last row is reached:

```
Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'set the Sheet you are using here
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with a value in column A
strURL = "https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com" 'set your initial URL here

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate strURL

Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
  DoEvents
Loop

Set HTML = ie.document

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to Last

    Set svalue1 = HTML.getElementById("Txt Box ID")

    svalue1.Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value 'enter the value from currect cell

    HTML.getElementsByName("Button Name").Item.Click


    Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
      DoEvents
    Loop


    'Do your data scrapping here, then below go back to your initial URL to repeat the process

    ie.navigate strURL

    Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
      DoEvents
    Loop

Next i

End Sub
```